# Repeated characters in string according to a given string and number of occurence

Tags: python, string, substring

I will give an example for what the code needs to return.
I have the string `"abccdddefggg"` and an integer `k`.

For `k=3`, the output is "for length 3, found the substring ddd".
For `k=1` the out put is: "for length 1, found the substring a".
For `k=2`, the output is: "for length 2, found the substring cc".

Let's say `k=9` and and there is not substring with length 9, the output: "I could not find".

I tried many codes, but I am not even close.

*Using only ifs, whiles, fors, lens but that's about it. A basic code in pyhton 3.7.

```
n= len(my_string)
i=0
for letter in range(n):
    if my_string[i]= K*(my_string[i])
```

Comment: that's what left from the code since nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "abccdddefggg"
k = 9

for i, char in enumerate(string):
    substring = char * k
    if string[i:i+k] == substring:
        print(f"for length {k}, found the substring {substring}")
        break
else:
    print("Could not find a match")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample function to nudge you in the right direction:

```
def find_sub(my_string, k):
    current, count = None, 0
    for char in my_string:
        if char == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            current, count = char, 1
        if count >= k:
            return k * char
    return None

>>> s = "abccdddefggg"
>>> find_sub(s, 1)
'a'
>>> find_sub(s, 2)
'cc'
>>> find_sub(s, 3)
'ddd'
>>> find_sub(s, 4)
None
```

Comment: Well, the code should help you still. Whenever theres' a return, you have the result and can `break` from the loop to produce you output.